# Android: change background color to PagerTabStrip selected tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I can see that in the PagerTabStrip, the selected tab just gets the tabindicator.

Instead of using the underline tabindicator, is it possible to change the whole background color of the selected tab?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's what I am looking for. I would like to change the background only of the selected tab and not of the whole PagerTabStrip.

Comment: Have you try with: pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.RED);

Comment: I would like to change the whole background color, without using the tab indicator. But I guess the whole point of using the PagerTabStrip is for using the tab indicator. So, probably if I don't want to use the tab indicator, I should not use the PagerTabStrip.